# Get one cortege by filter, django

Tags: django, database

In my Django project I try this to get **one** cortege from db:

```
rfc = HandledRFC.objects.filter(id==rfc_id)
```

And I get :

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable.
```

What should I do? Please, help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is:

```
rfc = HandledRFC.objects.filter(id=rfc_id)
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Worsed habit from c#/Java/C++